# Tests that don't include spec_helper being ignored in rspec runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

When testing `lib` code there is rarely any need to require `spec_helper` and load all of rails. This is why I have been removing `require "spec_helper"` in favour of `require_relative "../../lib/my_lib.rb"`.

These tests pass when called directly (`rspec spec/lib/my_lib.rb`) and are blazingly fast. Winner.

My issue comes when I try and run these tests as a group.

When I call `rspec spec/lib` it runs any `lib` specs that have a `require "spec_helper"` line but not any tests that don't.

I have played with `spec_helper.rb` to load in these tests, and that kind of works only it means that when I run `rspec spec/models/blah.rb` it will also run these `lib` tests, which obviously isn't what I want.

Is there a different way I should be calling my tests? Or is there a way I can get them added to the test run?

### Notes

My `spec_helper` is configured to run the tests in a random order, I wonder if this has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `_spec` to your files:

```
spec/lib/my_lib_spec.rb
```

Rspec rake task will look only for files which end in `_spec`.

Comment: Gah, I am a damned fool. Thanks @EugZol